# Running new 10/3 dryer line exterior first then inside?

Tags: electrical, dryer, conduit, exterior

Updating old wiring from aluminum. The current run goes up and over vaulted ceilings, then down to basement.

Looking to run a new line straight to basement but only panel access is exterior.

Can I run 10/3 nm copper in (exterior) conduit for 10ft, straight from panel, then into the basement to a 4 prong receptacle?

Do I need conduit the whole run inside or just for the exterior portion? Wasn’t sure with temperature of exterior to interior was OK.

Ideally would follow the metal A/C conduit there now then go into house.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Running exterior-rated non metallic 10/3 *cable* through conduit will be a task you regret biting off.    Try it on a sample piece first.   Even getting it through a hole in a 2x6 is hard.

Comment: @jay613   Just need the right size hole in a 2x6, say 3 or 4 inches and it is easy.  Just because you might be wearing the floor is no excuse.

Comment: @crip659 well then if you recommend a 4 inch conduit in an answer I'll vote it.  Not necessarily up.  :)

Answer (score 6):

You can't run standard NM cable (a.k.a., Romex) outside. That's in conduit or not, because it will get wet and it doesn't do wet.

You can either use THWN wires in conduit (which will be much easier than pulling cable through conduit anyway) and switch to NM at each entrance into the house. Or you can run THWN in conduit the whole way. Or you can use a cable that is rated for wet areas, and then you only need conduit where subject to damage - but since that gets you back to conduit, might as well use cheaper/easier individual THWN wires.

If you use metal conduit then you save on the ground wire as well.

Comment: Might be a dumb question - how do I transition from THWN to nm without a j box? My floor joists run parallel so I’ll have a straight shot to dryer room, but would be in rafters therefore can’t be THWN? Or do I just strip 10/3 of sheath?Thanks again

Comment: Can't strip 10/3 to use the wires - they are not the same as THWN. You either transition with a junction box of some sort or you run conduit + THWN the whole way.

Comment: @Jimbo you don't transition from THWN to NM without a J-box. You put a J-box in your basement up against the outside wall and run conduit into it from the outside and NM inside from there.